# how to print records in tpl file in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

How to print the records array in the tpl file?
This is my php code:

```
$inbox=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1");
  $inbox_rec=array();
  while($inbox_data=mysql_fetch_assoc($inbox))
  {
      $sent_mail_id = 12;
      array_push($inbox_rec,$inbox_data);
      $send=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2 where id = '$sent_mail_id'");
      $i=0;
      while($send_data=mysql_fetch_assoc($send))
      {
        array_push($inbox_rec[$i],$send_data);
      }
      $i++;

  }
  $smarty->assign(array("inbox_rec"=>$inbox_rec));
```

I want to view the records in tpl file as I have used the code in tpl file as shown below:

```
{foreach $inbox_rec as $value}
             <table class="table table-responsive">
             <tbody>
               <tr>
               <td align="left">
               <h5  style="color:#426AD5;"><b>{$value.mail_name}</b></h5>
               <h5  style="color:#426AD5;"><b>{$value.mail_email}</b></h5>
               <h5  style="color:#595959;"><b>{$value.mail_msg}</b></h5><br />
               {foreach inbox_rec as $detail}

               <h5  style="color:#426AD5;"><b>Admin</b></h5>
               <h5  style="color:#595959;"><b>{$detail[$i].sent_mail_msg}</b></h5><br />

               {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can print the record in your tpl file:

```
{$inbox_rec|@print_r}
```